# PvZ Garden Warfare graphical issues

Tags: pc, technical-issues, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I have a problem with PvZ Garden Warfare I just bought the game recently on PC and when I go in a game the graphic is not displayed correctly at all and it's very glitchy, I tried a test to see if I can run the game and I meet the minimum requirement, I tried multiple things and it's still not working correctly. The only thing really lacking is my processor but I don't see in wich way this will affect the graphics.

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60Ghz
/Ram: 8gb
/System: Windows 8 64bits, processor x64
/Graphic card: Nvidia GEFORCE GT 635M 2GB

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what's going on? Seeing what is "incorrect" could help us pinpoint what's failing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2yM8fs4

Comment: I even set the graphics to the lowest but no success

Comment: ok, so it loads up, but models don't load in. Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: Yes they are I even did an update after seeing the problem.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling, or if Origin has a diagnostic tool.

Comment: Same problem it didnt worked.

Comment: Have you tried turning your computer off and on again?

Answer (score 3):

The game is running although not showing all objects as expected, so I would have thought it would be a DirectX issue. The game requires DirectX v10 (or above) so I would try ensuring that you are up to date on that front.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely related to a video rendering issue. I would try these two fixes in this order:

1: Make sure you are using the correct video card. Find the Application file and right click on and select High-performance NVIDIA processor Like the below screenshot

[image: Picture of above]

2: Ensure that you are using the updated [Video Card drivers](http://www.geforce.com/drivers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your graphic card pilot, reparation by origin or simply check if you are using you good graphic card. On my PC i had 2, i change my graphic cards with Ndivia menu (right click on your deskop and choose Ndivia panels)